# Need a small sample application based on the technology stack (Durandal, Knockout, Require, Mongo and Breeze)

Tags: mongodb, knockout.js, breeze, durandal, hottowel

Currently, I am working on a project that is basically an ASP.NET SPA web application using durandal much like the John Papa's Code Camper SPA demo application.

The application is currently using the following javascript libraries/technologies:

1. durandal
2. knockout
3. require (AMD)

and NoSQL (MongoDB) as the database.

The plan now is to integrate the breeze to utilise its rich data management and other features. The problem is that the breeze is based on the concept of metadata. I have looked on the samples that were mostly based on the Entity Framework and those are not solving my purpose.

I have even looked into the samples in the breeze website with NoDB (Edmunds and Todo Lists) and these are also not solving the purpose due to the same metadata dependency issue as the application is quite big. Recently, a new sample named MongoDB (Zza Pizza Ordering) based on the BMEAN stack (Breeze, Mongo, Express, Angular and Node javascript applications) got released but the question is I didn't want to concentrate on including more javascript files (Express, Angular and Node).

Please provide me a small sample application based on the technology stack (Durandal, Knockout, Require, Mongo and Breeze) in case anyone have worked on the similar technology stack as I mentioned about.

Comment: I can see you are new here.  Stackoverflow is for asking questions to problems you face while developing. Try showing us what you have tried so far to solve your problem and provide code samples.  Then ask a very specific question.  Please refer to the help section for more information. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the samples [here](http://www.breezejs.com/samples).  You will probably not find the exact technology stack that you are using but the samples include examples of knockout, require, durandel, and mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [DurandalAuth](https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuth)  the Demo ist [here](https://durandalauth.azurewebsites.net/)  or [Pluralsight](https://github.com/kougiland/Pluralsight-CC-Angular-Breeze-Extra)  from  [john Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa)  i hope this will help you starting